# Numba CUDA speedup seems to low

Tags: python, performance, numba

Newbie starting with Numba/cuda here.
I wrote this little test script to compare between @jit and @cuda.jit. speeds, just to get a feel for it. It calculates 10M steps of a logistic equation for 256 separate instances.
The cuda part takes approximately 1.2s to finish.
The cpu 'jitted' part finishes in close to 5s (just one thread used on the cpu).
So there is a speedup of about x4, from going to the GPU (a dedicated GTX1080TI not doing anything else). I expected the cuda part, doing all 256 instances in parallel, to be much faster. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#logistic equation on gpu/cpu comparison

import os,sys
#Set environment variables (needed for numba 0.42 to find lvvm)
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvvm.so'
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = '/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/libdevice/'

from time import time
from scipy import *
from numba import cuda, jit
from numba import int64,int32, float64

@cuda.jit
def logistic_cuda(array_in,array_out):
    pos = cuda.grid(1)
    x = array_in[pos]
    for k in range(10*1000*1000):
        x = 3.9 * x * (1 - x)
    array_out[pos] = x

@jit
def logistic_cpu(array_in,array_out):
    for pos,x in enumerate(array_in):
        for k in range(10*1000*1000):
            x = 3.9 * x * (1 - x)
        array_out[pos] = x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N=256
    in_ary = random.uniform(low=0.2,high=0.9,size=N).astype('float32')
    out_ary = zeros(N,dtype='float32')
    
    t0 = time()
    #explicit copying. not really needed
    d_in_ary = cuda.to_device(in_ary) 
    d_out_ary = cuda.to_device(out_ary)
    t1 = time()
    
    logistic_cuda[1,N](d_in_ary,d_out_ary)
    cuda.synchronize()
    t2 = time()
    out_ary = d_out_ary.copy_to_host()
    t3 = time()
    
    print(out_ary)
    print('Total time cuda: %g seconds.'%(t3-t0))
    
    out_ary2 = zeros(N)
    t4 = time()
    logistic_cpu(in_ary,out_ary2)
    t5 = time()
    print('Total time cpu: %g seconds.'%(t5-t4))
    
    print('\nDifference:')
    print(out_ary2-out_ary)
    
#Total time cuda: 1.19364 seconds.
#Total time cpu: 5.01788 seconds.
```

Thanks!

Comment: 4X sounds reasonable to me.  It's not going to be 256x; there's a fair amount of overhead.

Comment: copying to and from the gpu amounts in this case to ~17ms, so the rest is in compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem likely comes from the very **small amount of data** and the **loop dependency**. Indeed, modern Nvidia GPUs can execute thousands of CUDA threads simultaneously (packed in warps of 32 threads) thanks to the large amount of CUDA cores. In your case, each thread performs a computation on one cell of `array_out` using a sequential loop. However, there are only 256 cells. Thus, at most 256 threads (8 warps) can run simultaneously - only a tiny faction of the number of simultaneous threads that your GPU should be able to manage. As a result, if you want a better speed-up, **you need to provide more parallelism to the GPU** (for example by increasing the data size or by computing multiple regression at the same time).

Comment: Thanks. This seems indeed correct. When inncreasing the number of calls to `N=16*1024` divided into 128 threads per block and  128 blocks, the timing becomes:
Total time cuda: 2.8771 seconds.
Total time cpu: 317.74 seconds.
So it improves significantly, when there are more parallel tasks to execute.